# Yukawa interaction with modulus

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, lagrangian-formalism, standard-model, interactions

In Standard Model, Yukawa interactions are generally written as

$$
{\cal L}_{Y} = y\bar{\psi}\psi \phi + {\rm h.c.}
$$

where $\psi$ is some spinor while $\phi$ a scalar (complex in principle), and $y$ the Yukawa coupling.

My question is, could I have another Yukawa-like term of the form

$$
{\cal L}_{Y}^{\ \prime} = y^\prime\bar{\psi}\psi |\phi | \ \ ?
$$

Does it make sense to take the modulus of an operator such as the field $|\phi |$?

Comment: No you can't. The Higgs field $\phi$ is there to make up for the differences between left and right handed fermion gauge transformations.  On the other hand, $|\phi|$ is gauge invariant, therefore it's incapable of fulfilling its purposes. The only bypass is to turn $y'$ into a field with proper gauge transformation properties.

Comment: I'm not forcing $\phi$ to be the HIggs